# Src-resolve: Cannot Resolve The Name 'xhtml:xhtml.List.class' To A(n) 'group' Component

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I am trying to validate an XML file against the following XSD file

```
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:imropt="http://www.geonovum.nl/imro/pt/2012/1.0" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" targetNamespace="http://www.geonovum.nl/imro/pt/2012/1.0" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0.1">
    <import namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink.xsd"/>
    <import namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" schemaLocation="IMROPT2012-xhtml.xsd"/>
  <!-- ================================================================= -->
    <element name="FeatureCollectionIMROPT" type="imropt:FeatureCollectionIMROPTType"/>
    <complexType name="FeatureCollectionIMROPTType">
        <sequence>
            <element ref="imropt:TekstMetadata"/>
            <element ref="imropt:TekstObject" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <!-- =============================================================== -->
    <element name="TekstMetadata" type="imropt:TekstMetadataType"/>
    <complexType name="TekstMetadataType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="verwijzingNaarPlangebied" type="string"/>
            <element name="typePlan" type="string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <element name="naam" type="string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <element name="beleidsmatigVerantwoordelijkeOverheid" type="string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <element name="naamOverheid" type="string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <element name="overheidsCode" type="string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <element name="creatiedatum" type="string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <element name="naamPraktijkrichtlijn" type="string"/>
        </sequence>
        <attribute name="identificatie" type="ID" use="required"/>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="TekstMetadataPropertyType">
        <attributeGroup ref="xlink:simpleAttrs"/>
    </complexType>
    <element name="TekstObject" type="imropt:TekstObjectType"/>
    <complexType name="TekstObjectType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="verwijzingNaarPlangebied" type="string"/>
            <element name="volgnummer" type="integer"/>
            <element name="niveau" type="integer"/>
            <element name="type" type="imropt:ObjecttypePropertyType"/>
            <element name="typeTekst" type="imropt:TeksttypeType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <element name="titelInfo" type="imropt:TitelInfoPropertyType"/>
            <element name="externeVerwijzing" type="anyURI" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <element name="tekstMetadata" type="imropt:TekstMetadataPropertyType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <element name="ouderID" type="imropt:TekstObjectPropertyType"/>
            <element name="interneVerwijzing" type="imropt:TekstObjectPropertyType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <element ref="xhtml:tekst" minOccurs="0"/>
        </sequence>
        <attribute name="identificatie" type="ID" use="required"/>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="TekstObjectPropertyType">
        <attributeGroup ref="xlink:simpleAttrs"/>
    </complexType>
    <element name="TitelInfo" type="imropt:TitelInfoType"/>
    <complexType name="TitelInfoType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="label" type="string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <element name="nummer" type="string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <element name="naam" type="string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="TitelInfoPropertyType">
        <sequence>
            <element ref="imropt:TitelInfo"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <simpleType name="ObjecttypePlanType">
        <restriction base="string">
            <enumeration value="afwijken van de bouwregels"/>
            <enumeration value="afwijken van de gebruiksregels"/>
            <enumeration value="algemene aanduidingsregels"/>
            <enumeration value="algemene afwijkingsregels"/>
            <enumeration value="algemene bouwregels"/>
            <enumeration value="algemene gebruiksregels"/>
            <enumeration value="algemene procedureregels"/>
            <enumeration value="algemene regels"/>
            <enumeration value="algemene wijzigingsregels"/>
            <enumeration value="anti-dubbeltelregel"/>
            <enumeration value="begrippen"/>
            <enumeration value="bestemming"/>
            <enumeration value="bestemmingsomschrijving"/>
            <enumeration value="bestemmingsregels"/>
            <enumeration value="bijlage bij regels"/>
            <enumeration value="bijlage bij toelichting"/>
            <enumeration value="bijlagen bij regels"/>
            <enumeration value="bijlagen bij toelichting"/>
            <enumeration value="bouwregels"/>
            <enumeration value="deel"/>
            <enumeration value="definitieve bestemming bij voorlopige bestemming"/>
            <enumeration value="document"/>
            <enumeration value="dubbelbestemming"/>
            <enumeration value="geldigheidstermijn van de voorlopige bestemming"/>
            <enumeration value="hoofdstuk"/>
            <enumeration value="inleidende regels"/>
            <enumeration value="lid"/>
            <enumeration value="nadere eisen"/>
            <enumeration value="omgevingsvergunning voor het slopen van een bouwwerk"/>
            <enumeration value="omgevingsvergunning voor het uitvoeren van werken, geen bouwwerk zijnde, of van werkzaamheden"/>
            <enumeration value="overgangs- en slotregels"/>
            <enumeration value="overgangsrecht"/>
            <enumeration value="overig"/>
            <enumeration value="overige regels"/>
            <enumeration value="paragraaf"/>
            <enumeration value="regels"/>
            <enumeration value="slotregel"/>
            <enumeration value="specifieke gebruiksregels"/>
            <enumeration value="sublid"/>
            <enumeration value="subparagraaf"/>
            <enumeration value="subsublid"/>
            <enumeration value="subsubparagraaf"/>
            <enumeration value="subsubsublid"/>
            <enumeration value="subsubsubparagraaf"/>
            <enumeration value="toelichting"/>
            <enumeration value="uit te werken bestemming"/>
            <enumeration value="uitwerkingsregels"/>
            <enumeration value="verwezenlijking in de naaste toekomst"/>
            <enumeration value="voorlopige bestemming"/>
            <enumeration value="wijze van meten"/>
            <enumeration value="wijzigingsbevoegdheid"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>
    <simpleType name="ObjecttypeVisieType">
        <restriction base="string">
            <enumeration value="band"/>
            <enumeration value="beleidstekst"/>
            <enumeration value="bijlage"/>
            <enumeration value="bijlagen"/>
            <enumeration value="deel"/>
            <enumeration value="document"/>
            <enumeration value="hoofdstuk"/>
            <enumeration value="overig"/>
            <enumeration value="paragraaf"/>
            <enumeration value="subparagraaf"/>
            <enumeration value="subsubparagraaf"/>
            <enumeration value="subsubsubparagraaf"/>
            <enumeration value="toelichting"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>
    <simpleType name="ObjecttypeBesluitType">
        <restriction base="string">
            <enumeration value="afdeling"/>
            <enumeration value="artikel"/>
            <enumeration value="besluitdocument"/>
            <enumeration value="besluittekst"/>
            <enumeration value="bijlage"/>
            <enumeration value="bijlage bij regels"/>
            <enumeration value="bijlage bij toelichting"/>
            <enumeration value="bijlagen"/>
            <enumeration value="bijlagen bij regels"/>
            <enumeration value="bijlagen bij toelichting"/>
            <enumeration value="deel"/>
            <enumeration value="hoofdstuk"/>
            <enumeration value="lid"/>
            <enumeration value="onderdeel"/>
            <enumeration value="overig"/>
            <enumeration value="paragraaf"/>
            <enumeration value="regels"/>
            <enumeration value="sublid"/>
            <enumeration value="subonderdeel"/>
            <enumeration value="subparagraaf"/>
            <enumeration value="subsublid"/>
            <enumeration value="subsubparagraaf"/>
            <enumeration value="subsubsublid"/>
            <enumeration value="subsubsubparagraaf"/>
            <enumeration value="titel"/>
            <enumeration value="toelichting"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>
    <simpleType name="TeksttypeType">
        <restriction base="string">
            <enumeration value="beleid"/>
            <enumeration value="beleid gemandateerd aan GS"/>
            <enumeration value="besluitdocument"/>
            <enumeration value="besluittekst"/>
            <enumeration value="bijlage"/>
            <enumeration value="bijlage bij besluitdocument"/>
            <enumeration value="bijlage bij besluittekst"/>
            <enumeration value="bijlage bij regel met voorbereidingsbescherming"/>
            <enumeration value="bijlage bij regel zonder voorbereidingsbescherming"/>
            <enumeration value="bijlage bij regels"/>
            <enumeration value="bijlage bij toelichting"/>
            <enumeration value="bijlage bij voorschriften/regels"/>
            <enumeration value="document"/>
            <enumeration value="regel met voorbereidingsbescherming"/>
            <enumeration value="regel zonder voorbereidingsbescherming"/>
            <enumeration value="regels"/>
            <enumeration value="toelichting"/>
            <enumeration value="voorschriften/regels"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>
    <simpleType name="ObjecttypePropertyType">
        <union memberTypes="imropt:ObjecttypePlanType imropt:ObjecttypeVisieType imropt:ObjecttypeBesluitType"/>
    </simpleType>
    <group name="rotext.content">
        <choice>
            <group ref="xhtml:xhtml.List.class"/>
            <group ref="xhtml:xhtml.Block.class"/>
            <element ref="imropt:verwijderd"/>
            <element ref="imropt:toegevoegd"/>
        </choice>
    </group>
    <group name="rolink.content">
        <choice>
            <group ref="xhtml:xhtml.InlNoAnchor.mix"/>
        </choice>
    </group>
    <attributeGroup name="listextra.attlist">
        <attribute name="type" type="string"/>
    </attributeGroup>
    <attributeGroup name="rolinkExtern.attlist">
        <attribute name="link" type="string"/>
        <attributeGroup ref="xlink:simpleAttrs"/>
        <attributeGroup ref="xhtml:xhtml.Common.attrib"/>
    </attributeGroup>
    <attributeGroup name="rolinkIntern.attlist">
        <attribute name="autoUpdate" type="boolean"/>
        <attributeGroup ref="imropt:rolinkExtern.attlist"/>
    </attributeGroup>
    <complexType name="rolinkExtern.type" mixed="true">
        <group ref="imropt:rolink.content"/>
        <attributeGroup ref="imropt:rolinkExtern.attlist"/>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="rolinkIntern.type" mixed="true">
        <group ref="imropt:rolink.content"/>
        <attributeGroup ref="imropt:rolinkIntern.attlist"/>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="romixed.type" mixed="true">
        <choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <group ref="imropt:rotext.content"/>
            <group ref="imropt:rolink.content"/>
        </choice>
    </complexType>
    <element name="interneVerwijzing" type="imropt:rolinkIntern.type"/>
    <element name="externeVerwijzing" type="imropt:rolinkExtern.type"/>
    <element name="verwijderd" type="imropt:romixed.type"/>
    <element name="toegevoegd" type="imropt:romixed.type"/>
    <element name="voetnoot" type="string"/>
    <complexType name="rotext.type" mixed="true">
        <choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <group ref="imropt:rotext.content"/>
        </choice>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

Following is the XML which has to be validated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="IMROPT2012.xsl"?>
<FeatureCollectionIMROPT xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.geonovum.nl/imro/pt/2012/1.0  http://schemas.geonovum.nl/imro/pt/2012/1.0/IMROPT2012.xsd" 
xmlns:xl="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:imropt="http://www.geonovum.nl/imro/pt/2012/1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <TekstMetadata identificatie="NL.IMRO.PT.1234.newtekst-1020">
    <verwijzingNaarPlangebied>NL.IMRO.1234.newtekst-1020</verwijzingNaarPlangebied>
    <typePlan>structuurvisie</typePlan>
    <naam>newtekstpoint16</naam>
    <beleidsmatigVerantwoordelijkeOverheid>provinciale overheid</beleidsmatigVerantwoordelijkeOverheid>
    <naamOverheid>testgemeente</naamOverheid>
    <overheidsCode>1234</overheidsCode>
    <creatiedatum>8-8-2016</creatiedatum>
    <naamPraktijkrichtlijn>IMROPT2012</naamPraktijkrichtlijn>
  </TekstMetadata>
  <TekstObject identificatie="NL.IMRO.PT.sFBC25A4F-6470-41F9-85BE-B134D5ABC08D">
    <verwijzingNaarPlangebied>NL.IMRO.1234.newtekst-1020</verwijzingNaarPlangebied>
    <volgnummer>1</volgnummer>
    <niveau>0</niveau>
    <type>document</type>
    <typeTekst>document</typeTekst>
    <titelInfo>
      <TitelInfo>
        <label>
        </label>
        <nummer>
        </nummer>
        <naam>newtekstpoint16</naam>
      </TitelInfo>
    </titelInfo>
    <tekstMetadata xl:href="#NL.IMRO.PT.1234.newtekst-1020" />
    <ouderID />
  </TekstObject>  
</FeatureCollectionIMROPT>
```

I am getting the following exception. Please help me understand what is that I am missing

Src-resolve: Cannot Resolve The Name 'xhtml:xhtml.List.class' To A(n) 'group' Component.

Please find the requred XSD files set from the given [File links](http://www.geonovum.nl/documenten/bestand-implementatiebestand-imropt2012) zip

thanks

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27706704/xsd-cannot-resolve-the-name-type-to-an-type-definition-component?

Comment: no it is not duplicate.

Comment: You have to post a [mcve] for us to help you definitively.  Otherwise, we can do is guess.  Probably one of the XSDs containing the `xhtml:xhtml.List.class` group is unavailable or improperly imported/included.  But, again, post a ***complete*** MCVE to get better help.

Comment: hi, thanks for reply, I have edited my question and provided an XML and also the XSD file set links in this question